# MPMoviePlayerController backward buffer video again

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am using a MPMoviePlayerController to play video from server.it's work fine,no issue.Now once i play buffered video and then go backward it start to buffered again. Is that a encoding issue or any other.Any help or suggestion would be appreciate

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *streamPlayer;

 NSURL *streamURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"];

    _streamPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:streamURL];

    // depending on your implementation your view may not have it's bounds set here
    // in that case consider calling the following 4 msgs later
    //http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8
    [self.streamPlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];

    self.streamPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    [self.view addSubview: self.streamPlayer.view];

    [self.streamPlayer play];
```

Comment: nsurl add on viewDidload method